# Refactoring pushing into different arrays

Tags: coffeescript

Is there any way I could refactor this in Coffeescript?

```
class Article
    constructor: () ->
        @rims   = []
        @tyres  = []
        @others = []
        @wheels = []

    addRim: (id) ->
        product = new SimpleProduct(id)
        @rims.push(product)
        product

    addTyre: (id) ->
        product = new SimpleProduct(id)
        @tyres.push(product)
        product

    addOther: (id) ->
        product = new SimpleProduct(id)
        @others.push(product)
        product

    addWheel: (rimId, tyreId) ->
        wheel = new Wheel(rimId, tyreId)
        @wheels.push(wheel)
        wheel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those add functions can be put into one

```
class Article
    constructor: () ->
      @rims   = []
      @tyres  = []
      @others = []
      @wheels = []

    add: (aryName, model, args...) =>
      m = new model(args...)
      @[aryName].push m

class Rim 
   constructor: (args...) ->
     console.log args

class Tyre
   constructor: (args...) ->

a = new Article()

a.add('rims', Rim, 'a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

The three identical functions could have their syntax dried up a bit using another generic addProduct method that takes a variable (an array) and pushes a new Simple Product to it.  Your addWheel looks different enough to warrant it a separate method.  I actually think the best solution probably involves doing something where addWheel creates the Rims, but I'm not sure how you use this model.

```
class Article
    constructor: () ->
        @rims   = []
        @tyres  = []
        @others = []
        @wheels = []

    addProduct: (variable, id) ->
        variable.push(product = new SimpleProduct(id))
        product

    addRim: (id) ->
        this.addProduct(@rims, id)

    addTyre: (id) ->
        this.addProduct(@tyres, id)

    addOther: (id) ->
        this.addProduct(@others, id)

    addWheel: (rimId, tyreId) ->
        wheel = new Wheel(rimId, tyreId)
        @wheels.push(wheel)
        wheel
```

The fact that wheels have rims and tyres, you may not need separate instance variables on your model for rims and tyres, it may be better to nest them like this:

```
class Article
    constructor: () ->
        @others = []
        @wheels = []

    addOther: (id) ->
        @others.push(product = new SimpleProduct(id))
        product

    addWheel: (rimId, tyreId) ->
        wheel = new Wheel(rimId, tyreId)
        @wheels.push(wheel)
        wheel

    rims: ->
        @wheels.map((wheel) -> wheel.rim)

    tyres: ->
        @wheels.map((wheel) -> wheel.tyre)

class Wheel
    constructor: (rim, tyre) ->
        @rim  = new SimpleProduct(rim)
        @tyre = new SimpleProduct(tyre)
```

Here, you could do the following:

```
a = new Article()
a.addWheel(2,3)
a.tyres()    // returns [SimpleProduct(2)]
```

This second example is only if you are trying to use `this.tyres` to access the tyres that are added using the `addWheel()` method.  For all I know you are using distinct tyres, rims, and wheels (that are tyres and rims).